# BB-code на PHP

Tags: поисковые-системы

Для продвижения сайта хорошо, чтобы сайт был живой, т.е. пользователи могли оставлять комментарии к страницам. Чем больше комментариев, тем выше позиция. Вопрос: Комментарии оставленные с помощью BB-code будут использоваться поисковыми роботами?

Comment: Что касается поисковиков, как я понял, алгоритмы держат в секрете. Но если учесть напор на качество и уникальность, то ВВ-коды к этому не относятся. Для живого сайта комментарии должны быть словесными и использоваться ключевые слова страницы. Только в этом случае сайт будет считаться живой.

Comment: @Monstrs-Inc Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно bbCode перед попаданием в БД (либо при получении из БД) изменяют на валидные html-теги.

---

#### UPDATE

> комментарии должны быть словесными и использоваться ключевые слова страницы

Обычно всё так и происходит. Посмотрите на здешние ответы и комментарии. Отвечают ли ИТ тематики ресурса? - да. Используют ли ключевые слова, которые указаны в title, keywords, description и в теле сайта? - да. Несложно привести любой другой ресурс, где эти правила естественным образом будут соблюдатся. К примеру, спортивный - в комментариях к статье, собственно, обсуждается описанное событие.

Давно прошли те времена, когда было модным искусственно создавать [SEO-кольца](http://slavkina.ru/?p=928) (в том числе и скрытые) и иные "штуки-дрюки". Косвенно к данному подходу можно отнести колонку "Связанные вопросы", которую Вы наблюдаете справа. И всё же, данный блок стоит отнести скорее к юзабилити. Нынче упор делается на качестве/уникальности контента и юзабилити.

**По вопросу:** Вы собираетесь парсить bb-коды на клиенте? Если да, то хотел бы Вас предостеречь - поисковики не умеют в достаточной мере понимать js. Да, [существуют попытки google исправить это недоразумение](http://habrahabr.ru/company/google/blog/224135/), но скорее всего, это ограниченный набор сценариев, и главное, как дела с этим у яндекса, рамблера (используется яндекс-бот),...
Проблема стала особенно острой, когда [стал повсеместно использоваться SPA подход](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable).

Язык упрощённой разметки bbCode, это без пяти минут уже история (legacy). Используйте [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). Вполне возможно, в ближайшие коды [он станет html стандартом](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Standardization), т.е. браузеры нативно научаться без проблем парсить его.

Answer (score 1):

Если BB-code при обработке редактором отправки сообщения **преобразуются в теги** типа: `<strong>,<ul><li>, <img>, <a>`,... и/или другие полезные для СЕО теги, а также сам блок комментариев **не грузиться** через `<Iframe>` или скрипт и **не закрыт от индексации**`<noindex>`,

то польза для СЕО будет обязательно! Это же качественный контент!

ПС: Еще для правильного отображение отзывов хорошо использовать микроразметку https://schema.org или другую.

Для интернет-магазина и товаров: https://schema.org/Review